# Obzedat Ghost summoning ability

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, summoning, ravnica, special-abilities

Going to run some undead for a boss fight, and while I was looking through some potential bosses I found the Obzedat Ghost. They seemed pretty interesting, in particular this ability:

> **Convene the Ghost Council.** The ghost summons the other four members of the Obzedat. At the start of the ghost's next turn, the other members appear in unoccupied spaces within 30 feet of the summoner. The ghosts each roll initiative when they appear.

Seems like a pretty good way to have a single boss turn into a squad of 5, but it got me thinking: if it summons other Obzedat Ghost, do those ghosts also have this ability, and in turn could summon another four, and so on and so forth?

I know from the story there's only 5 of the original counsel, but this boss isn't going to be in Ravnica so I'm wondering if RAW, it's technically possible for the ghosts to summon more ghosts and just overwhelm with sheer numbers.

Answer (score 4):

The RAW is that there are exactly 5 of them, and any can summon the others. They aren't creating ghosts, they are moving the existing ones.

But there is nothing stopping you from creating a very similar monster that can just multiply by 5x every round. I'm not sure that would be a *fun* encounter, but YMMV.

Comment: I think I'd give up the fight at 3125.

Comment: @biziclop at some point it becomes a 30ft radius packing problem, unless the encounter is out in the open

Comment: Luckily as ghosts they can fly and move through each other, so they can be packed in 3D. :)

Comment: Would each member be able to use Convene the Ghost Council to effectively teleport the other members around the battlefield after the initial summoning?

Comment: @L.P. yes, they could each do that